Proving that boundedness of a metric space defined in terms of radius and diameters are same without usage of triangle inequality

Diameter boundedness:A metric space $M$ is bounded if for all points $p,q \in M$, we have $d(p,q) <= R$
Radius Boundedness: A metric space is bounded if and only if for every point $p \in M$, there is a radius $r$ possibly depending on $p$ such that $d(p,q)<= r$ for all $q \in M$.

I am trying to prove that Diameter boundedness implies Radius boundedness.
Here is what I got so far, I have that for any arbitary point $p$, we can construct the set $S_p = \{ d(p,q)|q \in M \}$ by definition of radius boundedness we have that every element of the set must be less then some $r_p$. Now, we can do this arguement for every point in the metric space and get a collection $\{r_p | (s_p \in S_p) \leq r_p ,p \in M\}$ and then taking the infimum of this set...we should be done?
In the hint for the proof however, it was said that I have to use the triangle inequality somewhere. So did I do the proof wrong?

First of all the proof that Diameter boundedness implies Radius boundedness is easier than what you have done.
Indeed if there exists some $R>0$ such that for all point $p,q \in M$ we have $d(p,q)\leq R$ then of course for all $p \in M$ there exists some radius $r_p$ such that for all $q \in M$ we have $d(p,q) \leq r_p$ (just take $r_p=R$)
Now you have to use the triangle inequality when you want to prove the other implication i.e that if for all $p \in M$ there exists some radius $r_p$ such that for all $q \in M$ we have that $d(p,q) \leq r_p$ then there exists a (global) radius $R$ such that for all $p,q \in M$ we have $d(p,q) \leq R$

Have you considered reading the title of the question?

I believe this approach should not work. Take for example $\mathbb{R}$ with standard metric. If we take the point $0$, and consider a sequence $\{\frac{1}{n}\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$, and then construct the set $\{d(0,\frac{1}{n})| n \in \mathbb{N} \}$ and take the infimum of it, then we get $0$.
So, I suppose when proving questions like the one in title about metric spaces, we can't use an infimum/supremum based approach.
